# In a Drupal installation, how can I resend a user's activation email

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can an admin resend a user's activation email or allow them to resend it to themselves.

Answer (score 5):

If you block the users account and then unblock it, they will receive a new email.

Answer (score 1):

That feature is not part of the Drupal 6 core. I believe they're working on it for Drupal 7 but that's in question. If you know how to apply patches, [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/5688) provides a supposed solution (though not fully tested - test at your own will). Read both comments #5 and #9.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Seems like a pretty big oversight.